# run mocha task synchronously within setInterval

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have the below NodeJS script, which polls an address for web automation tasks and executes upon receipt. Polling and parsing response is fine, but I'm unsure how to synchronously fire the mocha test runner within the `res.on()` method:

```
var express = require('express');
//...    
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
//...

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

  var getTestTaskFromQueue = {
    host: 'remotehost',
    port: 3000,
    path: '/met/my/test',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  setInterval(function() {

    var reqGet = http.request(getTestTaskFromQueue, function (res) {
      var content;

      res.on('data', function (chunk){
        content += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function () {
        content = JSON.parse(content.substring(9, content.length));
        console.info("\nReceived Task:\n");
        //run one test via mocha here
      });    
    });

    reqGet.end();
    reqGet.on('error', function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  }, 10000);
```

And the test runner currently runs fine from CLI as such:

```
mocha test/folders/test_script.js --browser "firefox" --param1 foo
```

I'm evisioning stopping the setInterval loop at mocha execution start time and restarting it from a callback, but how should I execute the actual mocha test - from within the same script or talk to the CLI via subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `mocha.run()` to start your test once your environment is ready.

Though, what you search is probably *stub* and *mock* objects to prevent your test from interacting with external sources.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll give that a go and if successful update the original question with working code.